# Delete Database before it is being Backuped

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, triggers, backup

I'm using SQL Server 2008. now I want to create a trigger for capturing Database Backup. I watched to DDL triggers. but did not find anything about backup.

**EDIT : Really what i need to do. if someone will backup database i want to drop database. maybe it is not good to do it with trigger or event notification. if so then advise alternative way please**

Simply, how drop database when someone will backup database

Comment: yes i want to drop database before it is backuped. Do not want to give backup to others

Comment: Remember: anyone who as read access to the database can copy the data. You don't need to "backup" it to copy it. So you won't prevent "stealing" the data with that approach.

Comment: You said that database is no longer there. Yes you are right. I really want do drop database when someone right clicks on  database-->Tasks-->Back Up...

Comment: My comment to your second comment. You are right anyone who has read access to the database can copy the data. but i created database with filegroups. and it's difficul to restore database if user does not know anythink about my Data Base architecture. But with backup he(she) can easily get my data base

Comment: The user does not need to know anything about your database "architecture". It is really extremely simply to dump a complete database to text files. And there is no way you can prevent that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Event Notification for the `AUDIT_BACKUP_RESTORE_EVENT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190655%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) event.

> The Audit Backup/Restore event class occurs whenever a backup or
>   restore command is issued.

Comment: i watched http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2121/event-notifications-in-sql-server-for-tracking-changes/ here to create notifications. but not success. how use it? any sample please...

Comment: i looked and tested this code. but when i am doing backup no row added to EventNotificationQueue. can you give some working sample?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the [backup history of all databases in the msdb database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188653.aspx) available for querying. I'm not aware of any push notification system for backups but you can do polling and query over historical data.